# JScript variable assign

Tags: jscript

I'm running two Jscript file in a sequence(After first file is finished running, I will run second file). These two files are almost identical. The only difference is:

```
var version = "XX"
```

I assign different version numbers(say 5.0, 6.0) to this variable in each file and use this variable to further determine paths etc.

The problem is, when I run second Jscript, sometimes the variable `version` is still 5.0, which should be 6.0. And in the middle of the program, it will become 6.0 eventually.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to show how you run the two files.

Comment: @AlexK. I just use a windows task scheduler. Second one is scheduled one hour after first. First one finishes in half an hour.

Comment: I can think of no way the symptoms you describe could happen, A c/wscript process should start, run the script and terminate.  Nothing is left after that.